# Forms Auth requireSSl and Https

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

If my login pages are https, does it matter if "requireSSl" is true in the forms tab of the web config?

Currently I am redirecting pages with IIS to HTTPS. When I set requiressl it seems to cause problems.

Can someone put the two settings in perspective. thanks

Comment: I added the `ssl` tag for you, it should help you get some more attention for your question. : )

Answer (score 0):

if you set https at the server level then requireSsl does not matter (setting it on or off should not make any difference). After setting https required, set a redirect as mentioned in this article:

http://www.jppinto.com/2009/01/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis-6/

====
reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl.aspx

You can specify in the Web.config file for your ASP.NET application whether SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is required to return the forms-authentication cookie to the server by setting the requireSSL attribute